# Importar data de archivo excel a base de datos con AJAX y Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, ajax

¡Hola comunidad!, si alguien me puede apoyar a importar la data de un archivo excel a una Base de Datos usando AJAX. Usando Submit si lo consigo, necesito hacer lo mismo con AJAX. ¡Gracias por el apoyo brindado!.

Al usar AJAX muestra el siguiente error:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

Estas son las imágenes del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente código:

**RUTA**

```
Route::post('mantenimiento/validar',[ImportController::class,'import']);
```

**CONTROLADOR**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ARCHIVO IMPORT**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**VISTA**
Esta es la vista donde creo el modal

```
<!-- MODAL CARGA DE FICHA -->
<div class="modal fade modal-slide-in-right" data-backdrop="static" aria-hidden="true" 
role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="confirmModalCarga">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-Label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Cargar Archivo</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <!-- FORMULARIO SELECCIONAR ARCHIVO -->
                
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" 
      {{url('mantenimiento/validar')}}" id="formcarga">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <table class="table">
                    <tr>                                                
                        <td width="40%" style-align="right"><label>Seleccione archivo a 
 Cargar:</label></td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="fichaid" id="fichaid" value="">
                        <td width="30">
                            <input type="file" id="select_file" name="select_file" 
 accept=".xlsx,.xls" require /><br>
                            <button type="submit" id="bCargar" name="bCargar" class="btn btn- 
 primary">Cargar</button>
                        </td>                   
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td width="40%" style-align="right"></td>
                    <td width="30"><strong><span class="text-muted" style="color:red;" 
id="stexto"></span></strong></td>
                    <td width="30%" style-align="left"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </form>             
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" id="btnValidar" name="btnValidar" class="btn btn- 
 success">Validar Ficha</button>
                <button type="submit" id="btnCargar" name="btnCargar" class="btn btn- 
 primary">Guardar Ficha</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cerrar</button>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- FIN MODAL CARGA DE FICHA -->
```

**AJAX**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Creaste la ruta tipo POST

```
Route::post('mantenimiento/validar',[ImportController::class,'import']);
```

pero la estas llamando como tipo GET (tienes la peticion de ajax mal)

```
                       $.ajax({
                            url: '{{ route('MI_CONTROLADOR.NOMBRE_RUTA') }}',
                            data: {"id": id, "_token": "{{Session::token()}}"},
                            type: 'post',
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @ManuelRobles hice el cambio y sique mostrando el error.

Comment: Pon el nuevo código de ajax que usaste y si puedes una captura del network del navegador